# Dependency 'org.webjars:bootstrap:5.1.2' not found:32

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I add the maven dependency of bootstrap 5.1.2 on my pom.xml. But I received an error of *Dependency 'org.webjars:bootstrap:5.1.2' not found:32*. How can I solve this problem?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image]

Comment: First try on plain command line via `mvn package` also check your network connection ...

Comment: Does `mvn clean compile` from command line work?